# Game resources storing

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have the following table townResources in which I store every resource value for every town ID. I am a bit reserved about performance impact for a large amount of users. I am thinking for moving the balance for resources to the towns table, and the general value of an resource to store it in a .php file.

Here you have the townresources table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `townresources` (
  `townResourcesId` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `resourceId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `townId` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `balance` decimal(8,2) NOT NULL,
  `resourceRate` decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
  `lastUpdate` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`resourceId`,`townId`,`townResourcesId`,`userId`),
  KEY `townResources_userId_users_userId` (`userId`),
  KEY `townResources_townId_towns_townId` (`townId`),
  KEY `townResourcesId` (`townResourcesId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Stores Town Resources' AUTO_INCREMENT=9 ;
```

What is the best option in my case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best option is to test first. How much users & towns do you want to support? Triple that.. create the test data and see whether the performance is within bounds.

Answer (score 1):

If you run into trouble with performance you should look into caching the data with redis or memcache.